# Translating a quote by Marilyn Monroe

Tags: цитата

Question:

I want to translate the below quote into Russian.
Can anybody help me ?

> “I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am
>   out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me
>   at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best."

This is what I have:

> "Я эгоистичны, нетерпеливы и немного неуверенно. Я делаю ошибки, я
>   из-под контроля, и порой трудно справиться. Но если ты не может
>   справиться с меня в мои худшие, то ты уж точно не заслуживают меня в
>   моих силах.

I think the top part is more or less correct, however, I have problems with the last sentence ;)

Comment: Google translator detected =)

Comment: Which book is it from? I could look it up in an official translation. Cause mine is poor.

Comment: Can you provide some context please?  It really feels like a sort of a scam/spam email I often see in my inbox.

Comment: Hm, I thought it is from a novel, some woman in love, and pretty angry, and tears hidden deep inside. This way she probably retorted to her beloved' comment. He doesn't seem to understand her feelings at all.

Comment: Strange collocation : as hell... Never ever met it with a preposition. However, I thought it is an interjection and therefore translated it as "чёрт побери".

Comment: @AleksG: Actually it's (C) Marilyn Monroe ;)

Comment: @Quandary: it's attributed to Marilyn Monroe but it's unsourced and most probably fake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this site is not intended for translation requests, I'll try... Neither of the sentences is grammatically correct, actually. As well as my English =)

> “Я эгоистична, нетерпелива и немного неуверенна. Я совершаю
>   ошибки, необузданна , и порой со мной бывает трудно справиться. Но если
>   Вы не в состоянии осилить худшую сторону моего характера, то, чёрт
>   побери, Вы точно не заслуживаете знакомства с лучшей."

Well, something like that. Please note that I am not a professional translator.

EDIT. Official translation:

> Я эгоистичная, нетерпеливая и немного неуверенная в себе. Я делаю
>   ошибки, выхожу из-под контроля и порой со мной трудно справиться. Но
>   если вы не можете общаться со мной, когда я в плохом настроении, то не
>   заслуживаете меня в хорошем.
>
> С сайта http://www.inpearls.ru/

Where did you find the word "hell"???

Comment: I suspect the text is written from a woman's perspective, so it's likely to be _эгоистична, нетерпелива и неуверена_.

Comment: Yeah, I'll correct in a moment =)

Comment: A nice test on both double **н** and particle/prefix **не**. Took me a while to check  the rules. I'm sure it must be with double н and written together.

Comment: Yes, totally agree.  Depending on the context, it will be _не уверена_ or _неуверенна_ - that is, if _не_ is a particle, then one _н_, if prefix, then two.  My bad.

Comment: The full idiom is not "as hell", but "sure as hell". Aside from an obvious phrase like "hot as hell", the only situation I can think of where you'd see "as hell" is "sure as hell", in which case "as hell" essentially just means же. Someone who drives very fast and dangerously can be said to be "driving like hell" (note "like" rather than "as"). This usage is very colloquial, and more likely to be met in conversation than in proper writing, which would explain why you haven't seen it before.